# How to Enable Disabled different Input in Select Event using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, onchange

I want to do that when some one select the option one then 1st input is enabled using jQuery

here is the sample code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-material">
  <label for="storeCategory">Store Details</label>

  <select class="form-control" id="storeABDetails">
    <option value="message">Message</option>
    <option value="image">Image</option>
    <option value="video">Video</option>
  </select>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    <div class="form-material">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shortMessage" name="shortMessage" placeholder="Please enter the short message" >
      <label for="shortMessage">Short Message</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    <div class="form-material">
      <input type="file" id="image" name="storeImage">
      <label for="storeImage">Store Image</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    <div class="form-material">
      <input type="file" id="video" name="storeVideo">
      <label for="storeVideo">Store Video</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If message is selection the message input is enabled and when image and video is selection then image and video selection enabled and disabled.

I want the jquery how to do that please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to use [`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event to detect when the `select` was changed.
2. I was changed the value of **Message** to **shortMessage** so it will easier to get the value and find the right input.
3. Use [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function to enable\disable the inputs.

```js
var ddl = $('#storeABDetails').change(function() {
  var val = ddl.val();
  
  $('.form-material input').prop('disabled', true);
  $('#' + val).prop('disabled', false);
});

ddl.trigger('change')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-material">
  <label for="storeCategory">Store Details</label>

  <select class="form-control" id="storeABDetails">
    <option value="shortMessage">Message</option>
    <option value="image">Image</option>
    <option value="video">Video</option>
  </select>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    <div class="form-material">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shortMessage" name="shortMessage" placeholder="Please enter the short message" >
      <label for="shortMessage">Short Message</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    <div class="form-material">
      <input type="file" id="image" name="storeImage">
      <label for="storeImage">Store Image</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    <div class="form-material">
      <input type="file" id="video" name="storeVideo">
      <label for="storeVideo">Store Video</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```